# How to allow users to run (but not manage) docker containers?

Tags: docker

I would like to allow users of my docker containers (on a shared Linux server) to do

```
docker run
```

But **not** any of the other commands: build, inspect, ...

My use case is that of wrapped applications inside containers.

I was wondering if there is a best practice for this?

Comment: Considering docker doesn't have any idea of local users (besides group permissions on the socket itself), I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you could use a [sudoers configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/7484/5470) in order to allow to execute docker command only for `docker run`.
See "[How can I use docker without `sudo`?](https://askubuntu.com/a/477554/5470)" for the theory.

Make sure your user is not from the docker group, and use `sudo` to execute only `docker run` as `root`.
See as an example "[sudo / su to user in a specific group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209855/7490)"

Comment: I do not think that would work. docker run is not a separate command. It is still docker (run is just a parameter)

Comment: @TiagoAntao it does work: you can limit the arguments allowed for a command with sudo.

Comment: @TiagoAntao you need to add a wildcard of course (`docker run *`): http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178075/7490